# Show that the following Statements is true?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau $ be the topology on $\mathbb R$ for which the interval $[a,b)$ form a base.Let $\sigma$ be a topplogy on $\mathbb R $ such that $\tau \subseteq \sigma$. Then

1. If the map $ x \mapsto -x$ is continous for $\sigma$, then $\sigma$ is discrete topology.
2. If the map $ x \mapsto |x|$ is Homomorphism for $\sigma$, then $\sigma$ is discrete topology.

Please give me hint , how to solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: To show that a topology is discrete, show that each point $\{a\}$ is open.  To do that, show that some sets $[a,b)$ and $(c,a]$ are both open.

Comment: It seems to me that 2) is true vacuously. The map $x\mapsto\left|x\right|$ is not a bijection so cannot be a homeomorphism (if that's what you mean).